# Sorting Related objects in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models Category and Item. An Item has a reference to a Category.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Item(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    sequence = models.IntegerField()
```

The sequence field is supposed to capture the sequence of the Item within a category.

My question is:
What Meta Options do i need to set on category and/or item such that when i do:

```
category.item_set.all()
```

that I get the Items sorted by their sequence number.

PS: I am now aware of a meta option called ordering_with_respect_to .. but it is still unclear how it works, and also i have legacy data in the sequence columns. I am open to data migration, if the right approach requires that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
class Item(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    sequence = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['sequence',]
```

That will ensure that `Item`s are always ordered by `sequence`.

Answer (score 3):

```
category.item_set.all().order_by('sequence')
```

Comment: Is there a way to set a default ordering so that I don't have to manually sequence it each time ?

Comment: Thanks Uko. Would the order_with_respect_to that you have suggested, be on the Category model or the Item model?

Answer (score 2):

Kinda late, and the previous answers don't solve my specific question, but they led me to an answer, so I'm gonna throw this in:

I need to sort my `prefetch_related` objects specifically for only one view, so changing the default ordering is no good (maybe a `model_manager` would do it, idk). But I found [this in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects).

I have the following models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    ....

class Session(models.Model):
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    ....

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['start']
```

Now in a particular view, I want to see all the `Event`s, but I want their `Session`s in reverse order, i.e., `ordering = ['-start']`

So I'm doing this in the view's `get_queryset()`:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
session_sort = Session.objects.all().order_by('-start')
prefetch = Prefetch('sessions', queryset=session_sort)
events = Event.objects.all().prefetch_related(prefetch)
```

Hope it helps somebody!

*BTW, this is just a simplified version, there are a bunch of filters and other `prefetch_related` parameters in my actual use case.